# Azure Template with UI VirtualNetworkCombo hangs in "Loading..."

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-virtual-network, azure-rm-template

Created an Azure template with the Microsoft.Network.VirtualNetworkCombo type element. The new operation works fine. But two out of three existing Virtual Networks when selected show "Loading..." in each of the subnet dropdowns.

[Screen snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OD0IC.jpg)

I cannot figure out why 2 of 3 existing Virtual Networks get stuck in the "Loading..." state. Does anyone know what would exhibit this behavior?

***Update***
It has something to do with adding IPv6 address space (10:8:2::/64). Virtual Networks/subnets without IPv6 address space display fine.

Perhaps it is something to do with the constraints minAddressPrefixSize "/29" specifications for the subnets?

I sure hope the answer isn't IPv6 is not supported...

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in my environment it is working fine for me.

in `createUiDefinition.json` i have passed the below code in `"steps": [ ]`

```
{
        "name": "NetoworkConfig",
        "label": "NetworkSettings",
        "subLabel": {
          "preValidation": "Configure the storage settings",
          "postValidation": "Done"
        },
        "bladeTitle": "Networking",
        "elements": [
      {
        "name": "Configure Vnet Settings",
        "type": "Microsoft.Network.VirtualNetworkCombo",
        "label": {
          "virtualNetwork": "Virtual network",
          "subnets": "Subnets"
        },
        "toolTip": {
          "virtualNetwork": "",
          "subnets": ""
        },
        "defaultValue": {
          "addressPrefixSize": "/16"
        },
        "constraints": {
          "minAddressPrefixSize": "/16"
        },
        "options": {
          "hideExisting": false
        },
        "subnets": {
          "subnet1": {
            "label": "First subnet",
            "defaultValue": {
              "addressPrefixSize": "/24"
            },
            "constraints": {
              "minAddressPrefixSize": "/24",
              "minAddressCount": 12,
              "requireContiguousAddresses": true
            }
          },
          "subnet2": {
            "label": "Second subnet",
            "defaultValue": {
              "addressPrefixSize": "/26"
            },
            "constraints": {
              "minAddressPrefixSize": "/26",
              "minAddressCount": 8,
              "requireContiguousAddresses": true
            }
          }
        },
        "visible": true
      }
    ]
    }
```

**Output--**

[image]

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/managed-applications/publish-service-catalog-app?tabs=azure-powershell

Comment: I copied your posted code in to my template and got the same issue.

Do you really have an IPv6 address space, such as 1234:ABCD::/64, added to at least one of your  subnets (looks like it only has one subnet 'default', so is an IPv6 address space defined in that subnet)?

Comment: Hello @BlaineV, I haven't use IPV6 subnet in my code, Sorry missed your last update of your question. Can you please let me know the subnet loading for one of 3 vnet is that using IPV4 or IPV6?

Comment: Yes ,You are correct the problem with **minAddressPrefixSize** you might specifying /24 or /29 it should start with /64 as mention in this [Document](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ts3500-tape-library?topic=formats-subnet-masks-ipv4-prefixes-ipv6)

Comment: I changed **minAddressPrefixSize** to **/64** for, same issue. 

It is not clear on how setting **minAddressPrefixSize** to **/64** would be correct. I was thinking the size was based off of CIDR notation, but maybe that isn't correct.

Comment: Not finding any document that says Azure Managed Application definitions support IPV6 or not. I too hope it its not supported here that the resn you are facing loading issue.  You can ask the same question over MICROSOFT Q&A or You can also reach out to Azure Support as well.May they have proper details about it.